One liner command to ssh to server2, switch to another user in server2, ssh into server3, run commands in server3 and get output
Because I can only get to server3 from server2 (Server2 running CentOS7), I'm trying to create a "template" command or a script that I can use to :

ssh to server2
switch to another user in server2
ssh into server3
run commands in server3
get the output printed in the console

The template I'm looking for would have 2 parts, the first one to ssh into server2 and switch users to connect to server3, the second part would be the actual commands that I want to run on server3
I'm having trouble with this command:
ssh -t user1@server2 ‘sudo -u user2 ssh -t user3@server3 “command1; command2; command3”’

It connects to server 2 and switch users but I keep getting:
cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell

And when I add the --pty or -P flag to overcome the above error I get -P invalid option
I've also tried suggestions with script -q /dev/null but I still wasn't able to  run commands on server3
I'm open to other ideas to be able to run my commands on server3 as long as it uses server2 as a jump/hub/proxy server.

Do you really use smart quotes?

(1) Do you "switch to another user in server2" because this user holds credentials needed to access user3@server3? (2) You stack commands. Do you know what stage the error in question comes from? This probably can be determined by trying ssh -t user1@server2 date, ssh -t user1@server2 'sudo -u user2 date', ssh -t user1@server2 'sudo -u user2 ssh -t user3@server3 date'. Which command is the first one that throws the error?

@KamilMaciorowski (1) yes that's right, only user2 can access server3    (2) From the fact that I see i was logged into server2 and the user was switched to user2, I believe it's failing on the step before last , ssh into server3 . most of what've read about this error focuses on lack of a terminal, suggesting a pseudo terminal with --pty or -P both return "invalid option"

@KamilMaciorowski also looking at 'ssh -J' flag, but it doesn't allow for switching a user

@Tlink (2) So… which of my commands is the first one that throws the error? // About ssh -J: not "doesn't allow" (as if it was an arbitrary limitation), but it works differently. You need a daisy chain with sudo in the middle, but ssh -J gives you nested tubes.

@KamilMaciorowski thanks for the follow up, only the first command 'ssh -t user1@server2 date' shows the date , using the following commands I can switch the user but I don't get the date, that's as far as the commands go

"only the first command shows the date" – Does this mean the second command throws the error? Or doesn't it throw the error?

@KamilMaciorowski the second command sudo -u user2 date was giving '/bin/date cannot execute binary file'  but when I added  -c bash after,  it displayed the previous error cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device bash: no job control in this shell
